# How to find service dependencies for package updates on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

This question is similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/32566/how-can-i-tell-which-package-updates-will-require-a-reboot-or-service-restart).

When installing package updates, it's easy to find out package dependencies with `apt-cache depends`, however, I don't know how to find out what services may be affected. This is a significant problem in some circumstances; answers in that other question suggest that service restarts only take a few seconds, but that's not always true, for example a big MySQL instance may take several hours to shut down! Say there's an update to php5-curl. This is dependent on libapache2-mod-php5, which in turn depends on apache2-mpm-prefork. That package has 'apache2' on its provides list in `aptitude show`, so that tells me it's related to that service, but not necessarily that it needs a restart. I suspect that package dependencies alone are not sufficient to resolve this - I can imagine similar dependency chains that do not require a service restart (for example if the service loads such externals dynamically).

When I do an `aptitude full-upgrade`, I get nice output in "The following packages will be upgraded...". What I'm after would be a section in that output saying "The following services will be restarted...". How can I get that?

Comment: just use your knowledge. if you have such big and important services, you shouldn't ask for this feature.

Comment: Sorry, but that's a cop-out. Apt clearly knows which services need restarting, so it should be able to tell me ahead of time. That I have to use my knowledge simply means that the package manager is not good enough. It's academic anyway since I can generally guess what's going to happen, but my point is that I shouldn't have to.

Answer (score 1):

a way to find out definitively is to read the (pre/post) install scripts that come with the packages. maybe a grep "restart" is enough.

another way is to have a identical test system, where you could run your commands and see what happens.

Comment: That won't be enough because the services that need restarting may not be listed directly by the packages being upgraded - you'd need to crawl the entire dependency tree, not just those that are being changed. I guess the easiest thing would be to use the --simulate option in aptitude to dry-run the update.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create a script which looks updates for your system and like jojo said search for string "restart"